# How to write a dictionary list to a file using flask and python?

Tags: python, flask

I would like to add/write information to text files (on the disk) using flask (with just python the program works but when I implement it with the rest nothing happens).

`view.py` :

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['GET','POST'])
def add_entry():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        filename = request.form['file_name']

        read_file(filename) #returns a dictionnary list 
        write_file(filename)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else :
        return render_template("file_add.html",title='Add a file', items=items)
```

and `function.py`:

```
def write_file(filename):

    with open("app/static/DATA/{}".format(filename), "w") as f:
        global items

        items2 = [{ 'fixed_address': request.form['mac_address'],
                    'hardware': request.form['ip_address'],
                    'host': request.form['host_name'],
                    'comment': request.form['comment']}]
        items.append(items2)
        f.write(items)
```

Nothing happens when I submit, the file stays the same. What am I doing wrong?
I saw that `f.write()` might not work with other stuff beside strings but even the other solutions don't work and `f.write('random_string')` does nothing as well.

Comment: Try using a full path to the file.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you `f.flush()` after the write? But you'll need to convert `items` to a string before you can write it to file. e.g. serialise it as JSON.

Comment: Putting the full path didn't change anything (which is normal because my path worked with another function so it's not the source of problems). The "flush" function doesn't do anything neither. I just tried to do this without with putting random values myself instead of the "request.form['something'] and it worked, I think I should have defined web forms using flask-WTF instead of the traditionnal HTML input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) **Pass** `request` obj to your function to use it in it's body to retrieve POST params. In your code (when you do not pass `request` obj to your write function) you cannot get desired params because `request` is not a flask request object in write func body, just an undefined var. To use flask request obj in your function body - you need to pass it as a second argument:

view.py:

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['GET','POST'])
def add_entry():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        filename = request.form['file_name']

        read_file(filename) #returns a dictionnary list 
        write_file(filename, request)
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else :
        return render_template("file_add.html",title='Add a file', items=items)
```

function.py:

```
def write_file(filename, request):

    with open("app/static/DATA/{}".format(filename), "w") as f:
        global items

        items2 = [{ 'fixed_address': request.form['mac_address'],
                    'hardware': request.form['ip_address'],
                    'host': request.form['host_name'],
                    'comment': request.form['comment']}]
        items.append(items2)
        f.write(items)
```

2) Always use **full path** here `with open("app/static/DATA/{}".format(filename), "w") as f:`

3) **Use** `json.dump()` to write your data to a file:

```
import json

obj = [{"123": "123"}]    

with open("<full_path>", "w") as f:
    json.dump(obj, f, indent=4)
```

4) Do not use `filename = request.form['file_name']` - use `filename = request.form.get('file_name')` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very interesting, I will try to apply them to my code.

Comment: @Draga you're welcome! please accept my post as an answer.